# Nested IF statements, assigning value to column

Tags: sql, hive

I came across the following query in a closed repository:

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 join tab2 on tab1.event1=tab2.event2
WHERE
tab1.is_valid_num IS NULL OR 
IF(tab1.is_valid_num AND tab1.is_valid_name, 'A', 
tab1.is_valid_address AND tab1.is_valid_phone, 'B', 
tab1.is_valid_num OR tab1.is_valid_name, 'A', 'B')=letter_source
```

is_valid_* are Boolean fields. Letter_source should be 'A' or 'B'.
I'm running into all sorts of errors while running this query. 
Is it even possible to assign letter_source this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an assignment - It's a comparison.
`letter_source` should be equal to either `'A'` or `'B'` depending on the conditions.

The `IF` syntax is wrong. `IF` takes 3 parameters:
from [hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ConditionalFunctions):

> if(boolean testCondition, T valueTrue, T valueFalseOrNull)
>
> Returns valueTrue when testCondition is true, returns valueFalseOrNull otherwise.

So your query should probably look like:

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 join tab2 on tab1.event1=tab2.event2
WHERE
tab1.is_valid_num IS NULL OR 
IF(tab1.is_valid_num AND tab1.is_valid_name, 'A', 
    IF(tab1.is_valid_address AND tab1.is_valid_phone, 'B',
       IF(tab1.is_valid_num OR tab1.is_valid_name, 'A', 'B')))=letter_source
```

Also, in these cases, `CASE` is more appropriate and readable:

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 join tab2 on tab1.event1=tab2.event2
WHERE
tab1.is_valid_num IS NULL OR 
CASE WHEN tab1.is_valid_num AND tab1.is_valid_name THEN 'A' 
     WHEN tab1.is_valid_address AND tab1.is_valid_phone THEN 'B'
     WHEN tab1.is_valid_num OR tab1.is_valid_name THEN 'A'
     ELSE 'B' END = letter_source
```